# clicking button using vba failed

Tags: html, vba

I got this code to help import data from a web page, but it works up to where I need to click on button "Search Now"  :(

Any idea where is has gone wrong please ?

Thank you

```
Sub test()
'define empty row
Dim eRow As Long

'q where retrived from html code
Set what = .document.getElementsByName("q")
what.Item(0).Value = myjobtype
Set zipcode = .document.getElementsByName("where")
zipcode.Item(0).Value = myzip
.document.getElementById("Search Now").Click

...

Set objIE = Nothing
End Sub
```

HTML code for the button

```
<button class="btn btn-jobsdotcom" type="submit">Search Now</button>
```

Comment: I presume that `.document.getElementByID...` is inside a `With {x}` block, otherwise `.document` doesn't have anything to reference.

Comment: I haven't worked with HTML pages access via VBA yet, but I am pretty sure that you actually need to open and define the document first. Your syntax is also invalid as you are missing a with-block around the whole "q where retrieved from html code" part.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer and edit following code as per your requirement.

```
Set ElementCol = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("button")
For Each txt In ElementCol
    If txt.innerText = "Search Now" Then
        txt.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```